# Run expression at compile time VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, compile-time

Imagine that i'm writing my code and i want to know the current datetime...
Normally i would:

- create a new console project,
- put a breakpoint right after the main
- popup the quickwatch
- and evaluate `DateTime.Now`...

My question is: is there a way to this (invoke quickwatch) without having to debug a project???

Comment: How is that at compile time?

Comment: being the options Compile time and Runtime, i decided that compile was "less" missleading

Comment: Take a look at the FluentSharp REPL vs package

Answer (score 0):

You can run C#/VB code as commands with [Visual Commander](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/).